# Combine two datatables in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have two datatables. One is to display names. Another contains three `<h:selectOneMenu>`. I want combine those two datatables. I don't know how to do it?

Expected result:

```
-----------------------------------------------
Datatable1   Datatable2
----------------------------------------------- 
Lic          Date month year  
Premium      Date month year  
Test         Date month year
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways. One way is to grab CSS: add either `display: inline;` or `float: left;` to the both tables. Other way is to put the two `<h:dataTable>`s inside a `<h:panelGrid columns="2">`. To stylize it in a neat manner (fix/remove margins/paddings/borders and that stuff), just make use of CSS. Another way is to wrap the both datamodels in another datamodel and and just display it in one table.